# CRAN package submission: "Error: C stack usage is too close to the limit"

Tags: r, package, cran, submission

*Right upfront: this is an issue I encountered when submitting an R package to CRAN. So I*

- *dont have control of the stack size (as the issue occured on one of CRANs platforms)*
- *I cant provide a reproducible example (as I dont know the exact configurations on CRAN)*

### Problem

When trying to submit the [cSEM.DGP package](https://m-e-rademaker.github.io/cSEM.DGP/) to CRAN the automatic pretest (for Debian x86_64-pc-linux-gnu; not for Windows!) failed with the NOTE: `C stack usage  7975520 is too close to the limit`.

I know this is caused by a function with three arguments whose body is about 800 rows long. The function body consists of additions and multiplications of these arguments. It is the function `varzeta6()` which you find [here](https://github.com/M-E-Rademaker/cSEM.DGP/blob/master/R/varzeta.R) (from row 647 onwards).

***How can I adress this?***

Things I cant do:

- provide a reproducible example (at least I would not know how)
- change the stack size

Things I am thinking of:

- try to break the function into smaller pieces. But I dont know how to best do that.
- somehow precompile? the function (to be honest, I am just guessing) so CRAN doesnt complain?

Let me know your ideas!

### Details / Background

The reason why `varzeta6()` (and `varzeta4()` / `varzeta5()` and even more so `varzeta7()`) are so long and R-inefficient is that they are essentially copy-pasted from mathematica (after simplifying the mathematica code as good as possible and adapting it to be valid R code). Hence, the code is by no means R-optimized (which @MauritsEvers righly pointed out).

Why do we need mathematica? Because what we need is the general form for the model-implied construct correlation matrix of a recursive strucutral equation model with up to 8 constructs as a function of the parameters of the model equations. In addition there are constraints.
To get a feel for the problem, lets take a system of two equations that can be solved recursivly:

- Y2 = beta1*Y1 + zeta1
- Y3 = beta2*Y1 + beta3*Y2 + zeta2

What we are interested in is the covariances: E(Y1*Y2), E(Y1*Y3), and E(Y2*Y3) as a function of beta1, beta2, beta3 under the constraint that

- E(Y1) = E(Y2) = E(Y3) = 0,
- E(Y1^2) = E(Y2^2) = E(Y3^3) = 1
- E(Yi*zeta_j) = 0 (with i = 1, 2, 3 and j = 1, 2)

For such a simple model, this is rather trivial:

- E(Y1*Y2) = E(Y1*(beta1*Y1 + zeta1) = beta1*E(Y1^2) + E(Y1*zeta1) = beta1
- E(Y1*Y3) = E(Y1*(beta2*Y1 + beta3*(beta1*Y1 + zeta1) + zeta2) = beta2 + beta3*beta1
- E(Y2*Y3) = ...

But you see how quickly this gets messy when you add Y4, Y5, until Y8.
In general the model-implied construct correlation matrix can be written as (the expression actually looks more complicated because we also allow for up to 5 exgenous constructs as well. This is why `varzeta1()` already looks complicated. But ignore this for now.):

- V(Y) = (I - B)^-1 V(zeta)(I - B)'^-1

where I is the identity matrix and B a lower triangular matrix of model parameters (the betas). V(zeta) is a diagonal matrix. The functions `varzeta1()`, `varzeta2()`, ..., `varzeta7()` compute the main diagonal elements. Since we constrain Var(Yi) to always be 1, the variances of the zetas follow. Take for example the equation Var(Y2) = beta1^2*Var(Y1) + Var(zeta1) --> Var(zeta1) = 1 - beta1^2. This looks simple here, but is becomes extremly complicated when we take the variance of, say, the 6th equation in such a chain of recursive equations because Var(zeta6) depends on all previous covariances betwenn Y1, ..., Y5 which are themselves dependend on their respective previous covariances.

Ok I dont know if that makes things any clearer. Here are the main point:

1. The code for `varzeta1()`, ..., `varzeta7()` is copy pasted from mathematica and hence not R-optimized.
2. Mathematica is required because, as far as I know, R cannot handle symbolic calculations.
3. I could R-optimze "by hand" (which is extremly tedious)
4. I think the structure of the `varzetaX()` must be taken as given. The question therefore is: can I somehow use this function anyway?

Comment: Have you run `R CMD check --as-cran cSEM.DGP`? The option `--as-cran` is meant to address those problems.

Comment: Also, `varzeta6` is pretty scary. The formula it computes must come from somewhere, can't the code be simplified?

Comment: Unfortunately it cant. The code is actually copy pasted from Mathematica where we ran the calculation that produced varzeta6 as output. We used Mathematica to simplify the code. Without simplification the body of varzeta6 would have been muuuuch longer :-)

Comment: I did run `R CMD check --as-cran cSEM.DGP` (in Rstudio). There is no issue on my machine (I have Windows). The issue only occured on CRAN debian x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

Comment: When in the process does this happen? Maybe you can send the log? I had problems with examples before that did not run on CRAN servers or took too long, In that case you can use `\dontrun{}` to exclude the examples. Same is true for tests where you can exclude certain tests from running on CRAN servers.

Comment: You check the log here: <https://win-builder.r-project.org/incoming_pretest/cSEM.DGP_0.1.0_20200117_113938/Debian/00check.log>. I also hat issues with examples that were too long. That problem is fixed already.

Comment: @ManuelR I am pretty sure that the code for the various `varzeta*` functions can be simplified; for example you don't make use of the fact that many operations in R are vectorised. Take `1 - gamma[1,1]^2 - gamma[1,2]^2 - gamma[1,3]^2 - gamma[1,4]^2 - gamma[1,5]^2` as an example (from `varzeta1`). This can be rewritten as `1 - sum(gamma[1, ]^2)`. The other terms appear to be come about from some complex matrix operations. I would recommend re-written them in terms of matrix operations, which R can deal with quite comfortably.

Comment: [continued] If you give more background on e.g. the computation of `varzeta1` (to start with a simpler example) I'm happy to give it a shot.

Comment: @MauritsEvers I added some details! I dont know if it helps or makes things more complicated :-)

Answer (score 3):

Once conceivable approach is to try to convince the CRAN maintainers that there's no easy way for you to fix the problem.  This is a `NOTE`, not a `WARNING`; The [CRAN repository policy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/policies.html) says

> In principle, packages must pass R CMD check without warnings or significant notes to be admitted to the main CRAN package area. If there are warnings or notes you cannot eliminate (for example because you believe them to be spurious) send an explanatory note as part of your covering email, or as a comment on the submission form

So, you could take a chance that your well-reasoned explanation (in the comments field on the submission form) will convince the CRAN maintainers. In the long run it would be best to find a way to simplify the computations, but it might not be necessary to do it before submission to CRAN.

Comment: Dear Ben, yes thats what I am currently trying to do. So far there was no reaction from CRAN. We'll see...

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit too long as a comment, but hopefully this will give you some ideas for optimising the code for the `varzeta*` functions; or at the very least, it might give you some food for thought.

There are a few things that confuse me:

1. All `varzeta*` functions have arguments `beta`, `gamma` and `phi`, which seem to be matrices. However, in `varzeta1` you don't use `beta`, yet `beta` is the first function argument.
2. I struggle to link the details you give at the bottom of your post with the code for the `varzeta*` functions. You don't explain where the `gamma` and `phi` matrices come from, nor what they denote. Furthermore, seeing that `beta` are the model's parameter etimates, I don't understand why `beta` should be a matrix.

As I mentioned in my earlier comment, I would be very surprised if these expressions cannot be simplified. R can do a lot of matrix operations quite comfortably, there shouldn't really be a need to pre-calculate individual terms.

For example, you can use `crossprod` and `tcrossprod` to calculate cross products, and `%*%` implements matrix multiplication.

Secondly, a lot of mathematical operations in R are vectorised. I already mentioned that you can simplify

```r
1 - gamma[1,1]^2 - gamma[1,2]^2 - gamma[1,3]^2 - gamma[1,4]^2 - gamma[1,5]^2
```

as

```r
1 - sum(gamma[1, ]^2)
```

since the `^` operator is vectorised.

---

Perhaps more fundamentally, this seems somewhat of an XY problem to me where it might help to take a step back. Not knowing the full details of what you're trying to model (as I said, I can't link the details you give to the `cSEM.DGP` code), I would start by exploring how to solve the recursive SEM in R. I don't really see the need for Mathematica here. As I said earlier, matrix operations are very standard in R; analytically solving a set of recursive equations is also possible in R. Since you seem to come from the Mathematica realm, it might be good to discuss this with a local R coding expert.

If you *must* use those scary `varzeta*` functions (and I really doubt that), an option may be to rewrite them in C++ and then compile them with `Rcpp` to turn them into R functions. Perhaps that will avoid the C stack usage limit?

Comment: Hi yes the problem with gammas and phis is that I tried to give you an idea of what the problem is without mentioning other factors that complicate the problem even more. I value your suggestions but unfortunately if been there already. There is simply no way to solve this mathematically in terms of matrices and hence there is no way to rewrite this in R. If you are really willing I can explain the problem in full detail but this is better done via mail or on Cross-validated.

Comment: What might be interessting though is the C++/Rcpp way... thanks for suggesting that.